# Compare contents of Ref with PartialEq

Tags: rust

Assuming I have two `Ref<T>` objects where `T` implements `PartialEq`, how do I compare them?

The following code does not compile:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let a = RefCell::new("abcdef".to_string()).borrow();
    let b = RefCell::new("abcdef".to_string()).borrow();
    println!("{}", a == b);
}
```

and results in this error:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `std::cell::Ref<'_, std::string::String>`
 --> src/main.rs:6:22
  |
6 |     println!("{}", a == b);
  |                    - ^^ - std::cell::Ref<'_, std::string::String>
  |                    |
  |                    std::cell::Ref<'_, std::string::String>
  |
  = note: an implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` might be missing for `std::cell::Ref<'_, std::string::String>`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::cell::Ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#implementations) implements [`std::ops::Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html), which you'll need to use to get the value itself using the `*` operator. With your snippet, you'd want to do

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let a = RefCell::new("abcdef".to_string());
    let b = RefCell::new("abcdef".to_string());

    println!("{}", *a.borrow() == *b.borrow());
}
```

([Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bc110a91e6a177fe2017d3d3d779cacc))